# Driver License Barcode Field Data Types

Tags: c#, .net, barcode

I am given a task to develop a small library which needs to be able to read [`PDF417`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417) barcode located on the back of the [Driver's License](http://www.idscanner.com/id/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/reverse_side_sample.jpg) card and parse the data out to our custom object.

However I need to know what data types are these Data types denoting?

```
4/ANS, 10/ANS, 5/ANS, etc.
```

[image]

The complete documentation can be found at: http://www.dol.wa.gov/external/docs/barcodeCalibration-basic.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing here, but <field length>/ANS, where A is alphabetic, N numeric and S spaces?

For example, 3/A is 3 alphabetic characters like USA.

Funny that weight and sex are both 1/N, but the example given (2 in both cases) fits my hypothesis.

Comment: Seems to be consistent with sample data

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what about Height? It says 6/AN and the value contains a space?

Comment: Space is an alpha char

Comment: How it explains: Under 21 Until?

Comment: @ehh There are details at this link: http://www.aamva.org/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=4435

Answer (score 4):

The Washington spec is based on the AAMVA standard here:
http://www.aamva.org/DL-ID-Card-Design-Standard/

The 2013 ID Card Design Standard is here: http://www.aamva.org/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=4435

The PDF 417 barcode specifications start on page 51 (65) of that document.  On page 58 (72)  they list the type definitions: "A=alpha A-Z, N=numeric 0-9, S=special, F=fixed length, V=variable length"

Answer (score 0):

6 A/N means it is a 6 digit or spaced (A)lpha/(N)umeric variable.  For example 5'7" could be expressed as a variable that would fit the format as "067 in" (quotation marks only enclosing the actual variable.  Very common definition of terms usually found in Database programming. Your variable will always be 6 characters long (including the space character)--3 alpha ( in) and  3 numeric (067).